# Only interrupt another thread if in a critical section

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, race-condition

I have a method running in a thread and I only want that thread to be interrupted if it is in the given critical method/section. The method is being called from legacy code that has undefined behavior if interrupted.

How can I set up my critical method, and an interrupter method so that interrupts never leave my code into the legacy code?

I've tried using sleeps, and other techniques to reduce race conditions, but none of them eliminate them completely.

```
public class InterruptPlayground
{
   Thread _thread = null;

   /**
    * Implements some interface that legacy calls on "main" thread
    */
   void methodCalledFromLegacyCode()
   {
      try // critical section (probably wrong term)
      {
         _thread = Thread.currentThread();

         /**
          * Lots of fancy code goes here...
          *
          * If we are in here this section, we want the method below to be able to interrupt us, to inform us of its
          * impending death.
          */
      }
      finally
      {
         _thread = null; // part 1 of race
         if (Thread.interrupted()) // part 3 of race
         {
            // consume any interrupts in attempt to prevent race conditions, and prevent legacy code from getting interrupt
         }
      }
      /**
       * If the other thread interrupts us after this, the legacy code would encounter it, and how it deals with
       * interrupts is undefined (very legacy code, like 2000).
       */
   }

   /**
    * Called when one of our threads is about to die and we need to inform the above method
    */
   void methodThatNeedsToInterruptAboveMethod()
   {
      try
      {
         // if I did a null check, I could get a race condition, right?
         _thread.interrupt(); // part 2 of race
      }
      catch (NullPointerException ex)
      {
         // guess we were not in the critical section
      }
   }
}
```

Is this code free from race conditions?
Is it possible for interrupt signals called from the second method from escaping the first method (and reaching the legacy code)?
I'm worried about race conditions between parts 1-3.

Comment: that's not the way to deal with race conditions in java. you should use language features like "synchronized", mutexes, semaphores etc

Comment: A race condition is when multiple threads access shared state and might not see each other’s changes to that state.  I don’t see any of that here.  If you handle an interrupt and reset the interrupt flag (which `Thread.interrupted()` does) at the end of your method, the calling code won’t know it was interrupted.  It’s as simple as that.  Unless I have misunderstood your goal.